# Any Linux equivalent for the HttpDisk tool?

Tags: linux, mount, compact-disc

Is there any Linux equivalent for the [HttpDisk](http://openlab.jp/oscircular/httpdisk/index.html) tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fuse's [httpfs](http://httpfs.sourceforge.net/) filesystem ([fuse](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/))

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't compile on Fedora18. If you happen to know of any alternatives (ideally: rpm-based), then please do suggest. Else, I'll wait a couple days and mark your answer as final.

Comment: did you try to build the httpfs2? did you installed the fuse-devel (or whatever is called on fedora)?  can you paste the build log somewhere?

Comment: Getting lots of `/bin/sh: dpkg-parsechangelog: command not found` errors. I do have `fuse-devel` installed.

Comment: @Harry try just `make httpfs2` (623M of dependencies installing asciidoc to build a manpage... *facepalm*)

Comment: `make httpfs2-mt httpfs2-ssl httpfs2-ssl-mt` if you need https and *guess* mt for multithread

Comment: Okay, I was able to build httpfs2 and issue the command `httpfs2 http://fedora.iitm.ac.in/releases/19/Live/x86_64/Fedora-Live-Desktop-x86_64-19-1.iso /mnt/a`. But when I issue `ls /mnt/a`, all I see is one 951MB file listing for `Fedora-Live-Desktop-x86_64-19-1.iso` with no files or folders underneath! Is this how it's supposed to work?

Comment: Your link to me give 404 (not found), from the old httpfs web page seem it mount an iso directly without more mount needed, maybe you need to append `-o ro,loop`, but till yet I didn't found a working url.

Comment: Thanks, Alex, will give it a try tomorrow. (If it's working for you, it should work for me too.)